# How covalent bonding lower the energy of potential energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, molecules, binding-energy, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

Considering the potential energy of interacting particles, how does covalent bonding lower the energy of the system?

Comment: They are in a happy place.  You fill the orbitals.  Look at it from the other direction - it takes energy to pull them apart.

Answer (score 0):

They would not bond if it was not lower energy.  Like I said look at it from the other direction - it takes energy to pull them apart.   An O2 molecule is actually smaller than an  oxygen atom.  It is a tight orbitals that fill the orbitals.  Like hudling (spooning) from the cold.  S likes to fill (2) and then P likes to fill up (6 I think).  Actually 3 P orbital with 2 electrons per orbital as I recall.  If has been a few years since I took chemistry.